# jquery disable click over <object>

Tags: jquery, click

Can we disabled click over an `<object>` tag. I'm appending a player to the body using the  embed code. When the player is clicked it's taking the user to the players page, like youtube for example. This is interfering with the draggable functionality i have on the player. As soon as the player is dragged and mouse is released the link executes.

```
<object><param></object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

allownetworking="internal" 
http://jsfiddle.net/qAL5F/5/

This works for youtube as far as i know it.

Comment: It worked for me! Adding a <div> at the same level as the <object>, but after it. This will block clickes to the <object>

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 2:

You could position an overlay element over the object that will block the mouse click events.

[Test case for suggestion 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qAL5F/)

Suggestion 1:

The following doesn't work: [see test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Fpqsy/)

You can catch the click with

```
$('object').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); return false;});
```

I don't know if that helps here though.

Documentation for [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also...

```
$('object').click(function(event){event.preventDefault()});
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `.unbind()`  here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hyCEt/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `style="Pointer-events:none oncontextmenu="return false"`